# store data into class firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database screenshot >
   [image: database]

I have a class named Imgs

```
public class Imgs{
    public long nums;      //how many picutres
    public String[] url ;  //the urls of pictures
    public Imgs(){                           //constructor
        this.nums=1;
        this.url = new String[1];
        url[0] = "HELLO";
    }
    public Imgs(long nums){                  //constructor
        this.nums = nums;
        this.url = new String[(int)nums];
    }
    public Imgs(long nums,String[] url){      //constructor
        this.url = url;
        this.nums=nums;
    }

    public void setUrl(String[] url) {         //setter
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setNums(long nums) {          //setter
        this.nums = nums;
        this.url = new String[(int)this.nums];
    }

    public long getNums() {
        return nums;
    }

    public String[] getUrl() {
        String []a = {"null"};
        if(url!=null)return url;
        else return a;
    }
}
```

The variables nums & url in class Imgs mean how many pictures are there and the url of pictures

I want store dm/store/7-11's child nums into class Imgs's variable nums and the 
 dm/store/7-11/url's child 1~8 into class Img's variable url

This is what I have done:

```
public void getImages(String store){
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("dm/store/"+store);

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                imgs.setNums((long)ds.child("nums").getValue());
                int length = (int)((long)ds.child("nums").getValue());
                System.out.println("length:"+length);
                String [] tempUrl =new String [length];
                for(int i=1;i<length+1;i++){
                    tempUrl[i] = (String)ds.child("url").child(String.valueOf(i)).getValue();
                }
                imgs.setUrl(tempUrl);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I have declared

> static public Imgs imgs;

above the OnCreate() and I call this getImages function in OnCreate() like this

> getImages("7-11");

but I don't know why, when I run the program ,the logcat shows error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference

at this line

> imgs.setNums((long)ds.child("nums").getValue());

why? I thought I was right.

Can someone give me any advise ? Thank you very much.

**Update**

```
    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dm");
    myRef.child("store").child(store).child("url").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i=0;
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String tempUrl = (String)ds.getValue();
                i++;
                /*Handle tempUrl*/
                /*...          */
            }
        }
```

This work successfully.

Comment: That means `ds.child("nums")` is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public void getImages(String store){
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   // DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("dm").child("store")child(store);
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("dm").child("store")child(store).child("url");

    String url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,url6,url7,url8;

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      // String nums = dataSnapshot.child("nums").getValue(String.class);

          //    imgs.setNums((long)nums);

    if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0) {

         Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        if (map.get("1") != null) {
            url1 = map.get("1").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("2") != null) {
        url2 = map.get("2").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("3") != null) {
            url3 = map.get("3").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("4") != null) {
        url4 = map.get("4").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("5") != null) {
            url5 = map.get("5").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("6") != null) {
        url6 = map.get("6").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("7") != null) {
            url7 = map.get("7").toString();
        }
        if (map.get("8") != null) {
        url8 = map.get("8").toString();
        }

    }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If I put System.out.println("url:"+tempUrl); under String tempUrl = ds.child("url").getValue(String.class); It will show url: null

Comment: try this,  String tempUrl = ds.child("url").child("1").getValue(String.class);

Comment: you get the value,  then do this dynamically

Comment: same , the tempUrl is still null , but nums is 8 correctly

Comment: then you try again

Comment: String tempUrl = ds.child(String.valueOf(i)).getValue(String.class);

this work ! but tempUrl  print only 1 times . it should be print 8 times.

Comment: when I compile , it shows error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Comment: create a final .

Comment: this time the error shows java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

at  Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue(); 
and..If I don't know what's the nums store in database ,this method about create 8 variable seems  not a good idea?!

Comment: one question? 8 url is one user data

Comment: sorry , i'm update the code please try one more time

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by my way. anyway ,thank you very much.I'm very appreciate you for your help . I updated my answer.